# How to make my PCF app private to my company

Tags: authentication, cloud-foundry, private

I have a flask application deployed on PCF which is accessible publicly. I want to make the app accessible only to the people who have access to the PCF Organization and Space only. I tried to make the app internal by using `apps.internal` domain but it makes it completely private and inaccessible over the internet. What I want is a route which ask for CloudFoundry authentication whenever I want to access that domain and only after successful authentication forwards the client to the requested page.

I used the following resources:
https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/routes-domains.html#internal-routes

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing in the foundation that will let you accomplish this.

Out-of-the-box, you can make something public (give it a public route) or private (give it the `apps.internal` route).

There is kind of a hybrid approach I've seen as well. Where you use a public route but the DNS for that route is only resolvable internally or when you're connected to the VPN. Or a slight variation where the DNS resolves, but it resolves to an IP that is only routable on your internal network or through a VPN.

Another variation you can use is to put authentication and authorization in front of your application. The foundation will not do this, but you can have it coded into your application (for example, Spring Security can be used to do this with Java & Spring applications).

If that's not easy or you do not want to make code changes, you can map an `apps.internal` route to your application. Then deploy Nginx/Apache HTTPD/Spring Cloud Gateway or some other reverse proxy. Assign a public route to the reverse proxy and allow traffic on the container to container network between the reverse proxy and your app or apps. You can then use basic auth or other capabilities of the reverse proxy to further secure your app.

Ex:  `browser -> gorouter -> Nginx/HTTPD -> (C2C network) -> app`

Those options can give you the ability to control who has access but not based on the org/space membership. In fact, while you can use CloudFoundry's UAA as an OAuth2 provider, it's permissions are not tied into the org/space memberships either. They are tied to the clients, users and scopes defined in UAA.

To test for org/space memberships you need to specifically make a call to Cloud Controller. The problem is that there's not really a good API call to make to get this information.

You can fetch all the users in an org/space and check if the user is present, but that's fetching a lot of data just to validate. That's going to put pressure on your Cloud Controllers and not scale well.

It also puts the decision logic onto your application. It would be much nicer if the Cloud Controller had an API that would take a user and tell you if it's in the org/space, and I do not believe there is directly an API call that will do this.

The best you can do is to pick an API call that requires the permissions you wish to require and make that call. If it succeeds then the user has permission. If it fails, the user does not have permission. For example, [listing all the apps in a space](https://apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/16.22.0/spaces/list_all_apps_for_the_space.html). That would require access to the space to be able to succeed (it won't guarantee a specific role though, like space dev vs auditor). [Get space summary would be a similar alternative](https://apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/16.22.0/spaces/get_space_summary.html).

While these queries might be lighter weight, it's still going to have to query the Cloud Controller to make security decisions, and you'll want to decided if that additional overhead on your Cloud Controllers is acceptable.